# jQuery - Select Next Input/select by change in select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its been few hours i am trying to solve this.
My code

```
 <div class="conditions_wrapper">   
    <div class="ui grid condition"> <!-- first -->
      <div class="four wide column">
       <select class="select_column"><option> .... </options></select>
      </div>

      <div class="four wide column">
        <select class="select_relation"><option> .... </options></select>
      </div>

      <div class="six wide column">
         <input class="condition_value" type="text">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="ui grid condition"> <!-- second -->
      <div class="four wide column">
       <select class="select_column"><option> .... </options></select>
      </div>

      <div class="four wide column">
        <select class="select_relation"><option> .... </options></select>
      </div>

      <div class="six wide column">
         <input class="condition_value" type="text">
      </div>

    </div>    
      .
      .
      more clone of outer div . . .
 </div>
```

what is want is, when i change first select[`class=select_column`], it should update  of second select[`class=select_relation`] and placeholder of last input field.

```
jQuery('#conditions_wrapper').on('change','.select_column', function (e) {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  var valueSelected = this.value;

if(valueSelected == "value_of_first_select"){    
  jQuery(this).closest(".column").next().first() > $(".select_relation").html('<option> . . . </option>');

  jQuery(this).closest(".column").next().first() > $(".condition_value").prop("placeholder","enter email");

} 

else {

jQuery(this).closest(".column").next().first() > $(".select_relation").html('<option> . . .</option>');

 jQuery(this).closest(".column").next().first() > $(".condition_value").prop("placeholder","enter name");
      }

});
```

code works fine if i have only one condition, but with more than one conditions, change in the first select affects all second selects and all inputs.

how can i target only next select and next input only?

Comment: Can you give an example with real values? It is kind of hard to understand what you're wanting.

Comment: when class="select_column" is changed, i wan to select/taget class="select_relation" and class="condition_value", within same parent.

Comment: Screenshot: http://take.ms/7pzxb

Comment: current code is:    jQuery(this).closest(".column").next() > $(".select_relation")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing I noticed here is that on your html code you have `<div class="conditions_wrapper">` and on your jQuery you are selecting the ID `jQuery('#conditions_wrapper')`.

Here's what I came up with. You might want to refactor this, but it gets the job done.

```js
$('.conditions_wrapper .column').on('change','.select_column', function (e) {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  var valueSelected = this.value;


  // The this keyword here is selecting the "select" input
  // We can then select the parent which is the .comlumn
  // Get the next element which is the .column right after
  // And then get the child element which in this case it is the .select_relation
  $(this).parent().next().children().addClass('red');

 // The this keyword here is selecting the "select" input
  // We can then select the parent which is the .comlumn
  // Get the next element twice which is the second .column element from the select item
  // And then get the child element which in this case it is the .condition_value
  $(this).parent().next().next().children().prop("placeholder","enter email").addClass('red');

});
```

```css
select, input {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.red {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conditions_wrapper">
    <div class="ui grid condition"> <!-- first -->
    
      <div class="four wide column">
       <select class="select_column">
         <option vlaue="0"> .... </option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
       </select>
      </div>

      <div class="four wide column">
        <select class="select_relation">
          <option> .... </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="six wide column">
         <input class="condition_value" type="text">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="ui grid condition"> <!-- second -->
      <div class="four wide column">
       <select class="select_column">
       <option vlaue="0"> .... </option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
       </select>
      </div>

      <div class="four wide column">
        <select class="select_relation"><option> .... </option></select>
      </div>

      <div class="six wide column">
         <input class="condition_value" type="text">
      </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```